# Exact change - freecodecamp challenge

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop

I'm trying to solve Freecodecamp challenge:

> Design a cash register drawer function checkCashRegister() that accepts purchase price as the first argument (price), payment as the second argument (cash), and cash-in-drawer (cid) as the third argument.

I've almost solved it, problem is that it doesn't substract, for example "Twenty" as many times as it should.

```
checkCashRegister(3.26, 100.00, [["PENNY", 1.01], ["NICKEL", 2.05], ["DIME", 3.10], ["QUARTER", 4.25], ["ONE", 90.00], ["FIVE", 55.00], ["TEN", 20.00], ["TWENTY", 60.00], ["ONE HUNDRED", 100.00]]) should return [["TWENTY", 60.00], ["TEN", 20.00], ["FIVE", 15.00], ["ONE", 1.00], ["QUARTER", 0.50], ["DIME", 0.20], ["PENNY", 0.04]].
```

It should substract 20$ three times or 60$ , it substracts just once.

It returns:

```
   [["TWENTY", 20.00], ["TEN", 10.00], ["FIVE", 5.00], ["ONE", 61.00], ["QUARTER", 0.50], ["DIME", 0.20], ["PENNY", 0.04]]
```

60$ is added to "ONE" ..

```js
function checkCashRegister(price, cash, cid) {
  var change = cash - price;
  var changeArray = [];
  var val = 0;
  var n = [
    {name:"PENNY",value:0.01},
    {name:"NICKEL",value:0.05},
    {name:"DIME",value:0.10},
    {name:"QUARTER",value:0.25},
    {name:"ONE",value:1.00},
    {name:"FIVE",value:5.00},
    {name:"TEN",value:10.00},
    {name:"TWENTY",value:20.00},
    {name:"ONE HUNDRED",value:100.00}
  ];
  var den = n.reverse();
  
  
  var register = cid.reduce(function(accumulator, next) {
    return accumulator+next[1];
  }, 0);
    
  if(register === change) {
    return "Closed";
  }else if(register < change) {
    return "Insufficient Funds";
  }
  else {
    
  }
  for(var i=0;i<cid.length;i++) {
    val=0;
    while(cid[i][1] >= 0 && change >= den[i].value) {
      change -= den[i].value;
      change = Math.round(change * 100) / 100;
      cid[i][1] -= den[i].value;
      val += den[i].value;
    
    }
     if(val !== 0) {
       
      changeArray.push([den[i].name, Number(val.toFixed(2))]);
    }
  }
  
  
  if(changeArray.length < 1 || change > 0) {
    return "Insufficient Funds";
  }
  
  return changeArray;
  

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while(cid[i][1] >= 0 && change >= den[i].value)
```

Maybe I missed something in your code, but aren't `cid[i][1]` and `den[i].value` ordered oppositely? Also, wouldn't `cid[i][1]` have to be at least as much or more than `den[i].value`?